# What is it about std::cin that makes the program halt?

Tags: c++, input, cin, istream

My understanding is that `std::cin` is a `std::istream` object. `std::ostream` and `std::istream` objects hold a buffer of characters, or at least refer to them. When doing `std::cin >> myvar;` my understanding is you're using the `>>` extraction operator on the `std::istream` object to extract from the stream buffer. But I don't understand what it is about this that makes the program stop. I've been testing it and I've noticed that it only halts the program if it's empty it seems, because doing:

```
char c;
std::cin >> c;  // Awaits input from the console
// I input: 1, 2, 3
std::cin >> c;  // Extracts the 2, no halt
std::cin >> c;  // Extracts the 3, no halt

std::cin >> c; // Awaits input from the console
```

Basically I wanted to know is this behaviour part of the `std::istream` object. That when it's empty it halts until something is put in it ?  I tried to test this by creating my own `std::istream` object, but it wouldn't compile, an error saying something about protected.

Comment: *That when it's empty it halts until something is put in it?* Exactly.  You cant say you got input if there is no input so you wait for it.

Comment: The program doesn't halt. It's waiting for input, which is exactly the behavior you should expect when reading from an interactive device.

Comment: So an std::istream object is only ever used in relation to input from a console? I'm not understanding exactly, for example an ifstream object that you create when opening a file doesn't behave like this. It inherits from istream, does that mean it overrides its behaviour?

Comment: A file has definite size.  If you reach the end of the file you know that.  If the user hasn't input anything what would you expect to happen?

Comment: I guess I'm confused as >> is the extraction operator to get whatever's in the buffer. I didn't understand what mechanism was behind it pausing the program until there was something in it.

Comment: All operations take time. Some operations have no upper limit on how long that time is. Reading console input is one of those things

Comment: stream can be bound to all sorts of things. You can have a stream that reads a string, a network connection ..... They all have subtle differences in their behavior when there is no data. Some will report that they reached the end, some will wait for more data. cin stream waits for you to type more *and press enter*

Comment: @Zebrafish In CS, the term “halt” usually means something more permanent than what `cin` does. It’s used for when you actually quit a program, or turn off your computer, or something. What happens on input is just waiting, not outright stopping. The technical term is that it “blocks”; the call isn’t actually doing anything itself, but doesn’t return in a reasonable amount of time either. Other things that can block are network connections, `sleep` functions, and even writing (because you’re waiting for the disk or the screen, not the CPU).

Answer (score 1):

Don't get hung up on "the buffer". All input (well, usually) is buffered. That's a convenience, because reading a character at a time from hardware can be really slow; reading a bunch of characters at once and storing them somewhere (the buffer) can be much faster. That doesn't affect what's underneath. When you read a character, if there's nothing in the buffer, the system looks to the hardware for the next character. If it finds a character, it gives that back to you, and maybe it reads more characters and stores them in the buffer; the read function doesn't return until it's read the next character and done any appropriate buffering, or discovered that it's at the end of the input stream.

When you reach the end of an input stream, trying to read gives you EOF. When the input stream is text from a file, that's easy to detect: when you reach the end of the file, you're at the end of the input stream. When the input stream is the console, it's easy to get confused. The console doesn't have an inherent end: you might just be taking a coffee break and expecting to type more stuff when you come back. So unless you've told the system that the console is at the end of its input, it will just wait for more. The way you tell the console that it's at the end of its input depends on the system; on UNIX systems you do it by typing ctrl-D; under Windows it's ctrl-Z.

Comment: "_under Windows it's ctrl-C._" Wrong. Under Windows EOF is Ctrl-Z. Ctrl-C terminates the program.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius -- thanks for the correction. Fixed.

Comment: The line buffering does matter, even though the other forms of buffering under the hood mostly don’t.